# Setting Up Node.js so It Doesn't Crash Upon Encountering Error

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, server

I am currently creating an API for a web scraping application to feed data from the web scraper into MongoDB. I have listed my code below that converts a .csv file to .json and then inserts it into MongoDB. The issue is, I have an index set up so that no two database entries are identical.

Whenever this occurs, it throws an error (as it should), but it stops the running of the server which is not good. Would I need to use a try/catch statement for this? How would I format this for a try/catch statement? I just need it to continue running even if the database entry throws an error. Thank you for the assistance!

```html
csvtojson()
.fromFile("sample.csv")
.then(csvData => {
  mongodb.connect(
    url,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    (err, client) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      client
        .db("databaseName")
        .collection("collectionName")
        .insertMany(csvData, options);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Instead of just re-throwing the error, do something with it and handle it properly...

Comment: (1) `collection.insertMany` method has an option called "ördered" - and its default value is `true`. When set to `false`, the inserts continue even after encountering an error like "E11000 Duplicate key index error...". (2) Also, you can catch various errors (there are specific error classes) and act as needed by your application.

Comment: I am using ordered:false, that's what the "options" is in the function. Is there a node.js function to restart or stop/start the server upon reaching the error?

Comment: So it looks like it's error code 11000, and that pm2 does actually restart the server but when I try to run my script for a second time using cron timing, it doesn't run.